# Date of birth regex yyyy-mm-dd for rails app

Tags: ruby, regex, date, format, validation

I am creating a user signup form, and I am adding date of birth to the required fields.

I have scoured google, github and stackoverflow for a good date of birth (date) regex, and found this:

***user.rb***

```
DateRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/

validates_format_of :date_of_birth, :with => DateRegex
```

***new.html.erb***

```
<%=label_tag :date_of_birth %>
<%=f.text_field :date_of_birth %>
```

(I know that this will allow some bogus birth dates, but I prefer not to install anything like validate timeliness at this point.)

However, when testing the date of birth, it doesn't seem to enforce the 4-2-2 in the regex. It allows 2-2-2 sometimes, 2-4-2, 2-2-4, and it allows hyphens and slashes...help please?

Also, if necessary, how to I use 3 text fields and have it enter into one mysql date_of_birth column?

Comment: The code looks fine to me... Could you maybe post a larger part of your user.rb file? Maybe something else instead of the regex goes wrong.

Comment: The only other thing for date_of_birth is attr_accessible and validates_presence_of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always just use `Date.parse` to make your life a lot easier. If it can be parsed, it's probably a valid date:

```
validates_each :date_of_birth do |record, attr, value|
  begin
    Date.parse(value)
  rescue
    record.errors.add(attr, "Invalid date")
  end
end
```

This has the advantage of rejecting things like 99-99-99 and February 30th.

Comment: I tried this by pasting it in my user.rb, but it pretty much made everything an "invalid date". Help?

Comment: I was kind of lazy there rescuing everything instead of simply the exception generated by a bad date. You may be getting another type of exception that's simply being absorbed. Does `Date.parse` return useful results when using the console or does it throw an odd exception?

Comment: Bad, I know, but I don't know the console very well yet. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Should be easy to test with `irb` or `rails console`. If you don't know much about it you should spend ten minutes and explore, it's really handy.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
validates :date_of_birth, format: { with: /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/, multiline: true }
```