# Rails regex date validations in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a view that has two input's in it, both dates, and I want the user to type them in a specific format.  I created it as an index rather than a form, long story.  I'm trying to use Regex to validate the date's the user types in.  I want the dates to be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD, so if the user types in a date in a different format it causes an error.  Should this regex be placed in the controller or in the model?  I've tried validates_format_of in the model but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm also on rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065048/date-of-birth-regex-yyyy-mm-dd-for-rails-app

Comment: I need a specific date format though, that looks like it just checks if it's a valid date.

Comment: what do you mean by "validates_format_of in the model but it doesn't seem to be working" ? any errors?

Comment: No, no errors. It doesn't look like it's being called when I look in the tail.

Comment: can you show output from you experiments in rails console?

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :date, :with => /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
```

you saying validates_format_of doesn't seem to be working. What does it mean? Please give more information.